# Simple View doesn't respect GridLayout sizes?

Tags: android, custom-controls, grid-layout

I have to create a very custom interface that I was hoping to use the GridLayout class for (from the Compatibility library). To learn more about the GridLayout, I tried this tutorial here: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/686.

Everything looks good when using TextViews, but if you swap any one of them out with a simple View instance with a background color (or create a custom View extending the View class), the Views aren't sized correctly and fill the entire Layout. So my guess is I have to do my own measurement to size the custom View. But that has its own set of challenges since the MeasureSpec values you get during onMeasure are of the MeasureSpec.AT_MOST mode which give the size of the entire parent Layout.

So my question is, how do I size my custom View to behave like the other instances of the TextView class.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have a set of custom views, each of which represents a column. I need them to use the same space horizontally and as much space as possible vertically. I managed to do this by nesting weights, but I understand it is not good for performance. Therefore, I thought I could use GridLayout to obtain columns of the same size. However, my custom views use up the entire width of the screen.